# Cannot remove shaded background of carousel - CSS

Tags: css

LINK TO WEBSITE TEST PAGE:

[WEBPAGE LINK](http://www.newventureactive.co.uk/test2.html)

I'm trying to have a carousel with no background.  So the images and indicators are just displayed as is.

Have tried this:

```
.carousel{
     background:none;
     background-color: none; 
}
```

Which didn't make a difference, I also tried adding a placeholder as a background to see what it did:

```
.carousel{
     background: url(http://placehold.it/620x420/);
```

}

This added the placeholder background but behind the shading of the carousel.  I've uploaded an image here: [image: CAROUSEL SCREENSHOT]

Hopefully someone knows what I've done wrong, thanks in advance.

EDIT: Added HTML code for carousel:

```
                                            <!-- Image Gallery Start--> 
                                        <br/><br/>

                                        <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="max-width: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
                                            <!-- Indicators -->
                                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                                 <li data-target="#suniceCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                                 <li data-target="#suniceCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                                 <li data-target="#suniceCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                                                 <li data-target="#suniceCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                                            </ol>

                                                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                                                    <div class="item active">
                                                        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="/images/sunice/sunice1.png" width="350" alt="Chania">
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="item">
                                                        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="/images/sunice/sunice2.png" width="350" alt="Chania">
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="item">
                                                      <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="/images/sunice/sunice1.png" width="350" alt="Chania">
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="item">
                                                      <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="/images/sunice/sunice2.png" width="350" alt="Chania">
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                                  <!-- Left and right controls -->
                                                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                                  </a>
                                                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#Carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                                  </a>                                                

                                        </div>
                                    </br></br>
                                    <!-- Image gallery end-->
```

Comment: are you using any plugin for the carousel? it's impossible for us to help without a working example

Comment: Can you show us your code? Or post a link of your website?

Comment: `background: transparent` is the correct value, if it's not working due overrides or specificity please, try `background: transparent !important`

Comment: Hi Marcos, that still doesn't work I'm afraid, I've checked the inspector and that attribute is being applied, if I change transparent to white a white background appears.

Comment: @MHarkess try with this  #Carousel.carousel(background:none !important;)

Comment: @MHarkess if the style it's applyed your problem is in another element, if not I don't understand why a rule is applyed but it renders another thing. So if you want we help you to solve this, please, share a working example (stacksnippets or external services like jsfiddle.net), reproducing the issue. See more: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  ||| http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi Maheshv: That doesn't work either I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked the online example, the carousel adds the class `active` to the current active item.
In your `style.css`  the `active` class has the following style:

```
.active{
    background: url("images/active-bg.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

you just need to remove the `background` property and you'll have a transparent background for every carousel item.

Comment: @MHarkess No problem! glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood you just want to remove the gradient the chevrons have for a background?

```
#Carousel .carousel-control.left,
#Carousel .carousel-control.right {
  background-image: none;
}
```

This should be all you need. Here is an example below

```css
#Carousel .carousel-control.left,
#Carousel .carousel-control.right {
  background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Image Gallery Start-->
<br/>
<br/>

<div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="max-width: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#suniceCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#suniceCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#suniceCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#suniceCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <div class="item active">
      <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://www.newventureactive.co.uk/images/sunice/sunice1.png" width="350" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://www.newventureactive.co.uk/images/sunice/sunice2.png" width="350" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://www.newventureactive.co.uk/images/sunice/sunice1.png" width="350" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://www.newventureactive.co.uk/images/sunice/sunice2.png" width="350" alt="Chania">
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#Carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</div>
</br>
</br>
<!-- Image gallery end-->
```

Comment: That's pretty confusing, works perfectly outside of the <divs> so obviously something is adding that background to it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

**Try This**

```
.carousel-inner .active{
     background:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only this worked:

```html
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" style="background-image:none">
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" style="background-image:none">
```

Nothing else worked for me.